# jQuery $.ajax() is working when type:html or text but not working when type:json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, xmlhttprequest

here is my my code:

```
<script>
    $.ajax({
        url:url, /* ./ajax/data.json */
        type:'post',
        dataType:'text', /* text,html,json,jsonp */
        /*contentType: 'application/json',*/
        async:true,
        success: function(data){
            console.log(arguments);
            alert('success');
        },
        error: function(){
            alert('failed');
        }
    });
</script>
```

I get the response and alert('success') when type:'text' & type:'html', 
but I get alert('failed') when I try type:'jsonp'

Update: Json file

```
{
  data1:{'Data 1'},
  data2:{'Data 2'},
  data3:{'Data 3'},
  data4:{'Data 4'},
  data5:{'Data 5'},
  data6:{'Data 6'},
  data7:{'Data 7'},
  data8:{'Data 8'},
  data9:{'Data 9'},
}
```

Comment: In response from the server, you need to JSON if you use `dataType: 'JSON'`

Comment: So the problem is with json or jsonp?

Comment: The `error` handler receives **three arguments**: _"The `jqXHR` (in jQuery 1.4.x, `XMLHttpRequest`) object, **a string describing the type of error that occurred** and an optional exception object, if one occurred."_

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is, I need to get the response as json.

Comment: when you are using `dataType;'json',` then you have to send json response from server side.can you show your server side code?

Comment: I'm not using server code. 
my current <script> is in index.html, and the requested file (data.json) is in ./ajax/data.json

Comment: show that file data. if large then some part of it otherwise complete

Comment: my project is in a folder in 'htdoc'
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B6sq6odqLVB3azhDRkxpWjE4cjA?usp=sharing

Comment: here is the whole folder in google drive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code ajax call type must be `'get'`.
The main problem is in your json file.

your json file

```
{
  data1:{'Data 1'},
  data2:{'Data 2'},
  data3:{'Data 3'},
  data4:{'Data 4'},
  data5:{'Data 5'},
  data6:{'Data 6'},
  data7:{'Data 7'},
  data8:{'Data 8'},
  data9:{'Data 9'},
}
```

is not valid Json format

I have changed to

```
{
  "data1":"Data 1",
  "data2":"Data 2",
  ...
  "data9":"Data 9"
}
```

and it alerts success.

Comment: I changed the json { 'data1' : 'some data' } which didn't work, but it worked { 
"data1" : "some data" } :)